# Github - multiple html pages do not load when published, only the index.html one

Tags: github, upload

Just finished my first website made from scratch (still in the learning process, so still a rookie here) and now I have to upload my project in order to be graded. I am using Github for this, I followed all the steps I found online to upload everything and all ...I have four html pages - an "index" one, "about", "books&travel" and "more", the only problem is that only the index page opens up ...the rest appear as menu links, but when clicking on them, NOTHING happens. What I am doing wrong?
(The pages are all linked to each other using the  tag - when not published the menu links work just fine, I can navigate from one page to another, but when uploading on Github, nothing happens...not even the 404 error, it just does not load up the new page)
Please help!
Thanks!

I tried renaming the  to be the same as the menu titles, but it did not work.
Also, I am trying to figure out if this issue has to do with the way I have uploaded the files on Github (?)

Comment: This sounds like wrong links. Could you post your anchor (a) tags? If you are on the local (not published) version and link to e.g. "localhost:3000/about" it will work. Online the URL will be something like yourname.github.io/about. You should use relative links (linking to '/about' instead of 'localhost:3000/about'.

Comment: Try to post your index.html code file using the code blocks :)

Comment: Hi @dbice! Thanks for the reply! So this is one of my links - <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/Luiza/Desktop/incercare%20trei%20responsive%20menu/About.html">About</a></li>

Answer (score 0):

When you use a link like About, you're creating an absolute file path. This works locally on your computer because it's referencing a file path on your local system (file:///C:/Users/Luiza/Desktop/incercare%20trei%20responsive%20menu/About.html), but it won't work once you've uploaded your project to GitHub Pages because GitHub Pages serves your website online, where the path is your URL.

To fix this, you need to use relative paths instead of absolute paths. Relative paths are paths that are relative to the current location of the file. Assuming your about.html file is in the same directory as your index.html, you should use a link like this:

```
<a href="about.html">About</a>
```

This way, the link will work regardless if your project is run locally or on GitHub Pages. Change this in every link you use.
Then you can upload your changes to github

Comment: it worked! I guess I never thought the moment to publish my own page will come eventually and I moved too fast over the absolute vs relative links lessons... Thanks for the help!